# Should I use vagrant halt before restarting host

Tags: vagrant

I am kind of new to using vagrant with oracle's virtual box. I was wondering if anyone knows if it is a good idea or not to use vagrant halt before restarting or rebooting my host machine?

Answer (score 2):

> Vagrant halt

is another way of saying shutdown; it is a good practice to do that since it will attempt to shut the VM gracefully where as windows will force it to. As a result you may sometimes get an error saying the VM wasn't shut properly and is now on a protected mode or saved mode and need to be rebuilt.